# How to change style sheets in parsed pages by the Glype PHP proxy?

Tags: parsing, proxy

Is there a plugin or how do I to change style sheet links on a certain web pages that is parsed by [Glype](http://www.glype.com/)?

I need to change the look and the colors of a remote hosted application to match my website theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the way to do it. Steps:

1. Create a plugin file in the plugin folder of Glype.
2. The plugin file name should be the same as the domain you are trying to edit.
3. Use the `preParse` function to do a regular expression replacement of stylesheet URLs.

   ```
   function preParse($input, $type) {

     # Fix thumbnail images
      $input = preg_replace(
                 '<link href="Url_One" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />',
                 'link href="Url_Two" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /',
                 $input);

     return $input;
   }
   ```